# UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification not called on iPhone X

Tags: ios, keyboard, iphone-x

UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification is sometimes not being called whilst the keyboard is changing. It works well on all devices except on the iPhone X. Is this a bug?

Comment: For me, it's only an issue when Predictive is OFF in Settings > General > Keyboard and when trying to showing the emoji keyboard.

Answer (score -1):

Same problem with real iPhone X device running 11.2.1.

The UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification is not sent to app when returning from Settings > General > Keyboard and changing "Predictive".

Strangely it does get sent in the Simulator to the app.